# Magento show related products php code

Tags: php, magento, product

Hope somebody can help me out here.

What I'm try to do, is to show related products, when you're landing on a products page.

**Let's say:**

I have a categori, the name is computer. In that computer category, I have 3 products a Acer laptop, a HP laptop and a Apple macbook air.

If my customer click on the mac - how can I then show the related products? (eg. the Acer and the HP laptop).

I don't want to edit the catelog.xml - allready tryed that, whitout any luck.

**I allready got som php file**
 - And it sort-of working, but when the customer lands on one of the product page, they also sees the product, that they're reading about - how can I remove the current product from the list?

```
<?php
        $currentCategoryId = Mage::getModel('catalog/layer')->getCurrentCategory()->getId();
        $product_id = $this->getProduct()->getId();

        echo $product_id;

        $categoryid = $currentCategoryId;

        $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
        $category->load($categoryid);
        $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
        $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

        foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>

    <?php } ?>
```

It takes all the products from the entire category, and then displays them on the current productpage.
I really hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

1) using filter

```
 ...
 $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('neq', $product_id));
```

2) using if statement to filter out the id

```
 ....
 foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>
     <?php if($_product->getId() != $product_id) : ?>
        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>">...</a>
     <?php endif;?>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use it like this in view.phtml

```
 $related_prods = $_product->getRelatedProductIds()
```

foreach($related_prods as $related)

{

$_rel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($related);

echo $_rel->getName() . " " . $_rel->getSku();

}

Comment: This is copy and paste from somewhere else (http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3177/showing-related-products-in-product-view-page), where the original author admits that this is a terrible implementation.